# is it possible to create wds in laptop,wireless distribution setup

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I have WiFi connection for my laptop. Is it possible to create another WiFi as AP from laptop using the base WiFi internet connection. I know it is possible to create WiFi from wired connection via laptop. Is it possible like WiFi to WiFi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with some wireless adapters.

I don't know what OS you are using, but for Windows, you can do the following.

---

Firstly, open a `cmd` prompt and type the command `netsh wlan show drivers`. You'll get an output like this:

```
Interface name: Wi-Fi 2

    Driver                    : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
    Vendor                    : Intel Corporation
    Provider                  : Intel
    Date                      : 24/09/2015
    Version                   : 18.21.0.2
    INF file                  : C:\WINDOWS\INF\oem43.inf
    Files                     : 2 total
                                C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\Netwbw02.sys
                                C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\Netwfw02.dat
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
    Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n 802.11a 802.11ac
    FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
    802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
    Hosted network supported  : Yes
    Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                                Open            None
                                Open            WEP-40bit
                                Open            WEP-104bit
                                Open            WEP
                                WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                                WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                                WPA-Personal    TKIP
                                WPA-Personal    CCMP
                                WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                                WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                                WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                                Open            Vendor defined
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
    Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                                Open            None
                                Open            WEP-40bit
                                Open            WEP-104bit
                                Open            WEP
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
    IHV service present       : Yes
    IHV adapter OUI           : [00 80 86], type: [00]
    IHV extensibility DLL path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\IWMSSvc.dll
    IHV UI extensibility ClSID: {1bf6cb2d-2ae0-4879-a7aa-a75834fbd0e3}
    IHV diagnostics CLSID     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

If your output contains `Hosted network supported  : Yes` then you can proceed, otherwise the rest of the steps won't work.

Now, use the command `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=SSIDNAME key=WPA2PASSKEY` to set up your SSID and Passkey (The pass key must be atleast 8 characters).

Assuming this works, you can now use `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` to start your new wireless point.

From here, go to your `Network Connections`, go to `Properties` for your actual wireless card, go to `Sharing` and enable `Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection`, sharing it with your new adapter.

[image]

Clients can now connect to your new SSID and access the connection from your WiFi.